# Complete manifold and the Hopf–Rinow theorem

Tags: differential-geometry

A unit disk with the Euclidean metric should be complete as a metric space.

But it is not geodesically complete I guess. Since every line will reach the boundary and can not be defined for all $t$.

But the Hopf–Rinow theorem says these two concepts are equivalent.

What is wrong in the above arguments...

Thanks,

Comment: Why *should* the disk be complete? That's a weird statement, given that it is not!

Comment: I mean closed disk...

Comment: Then it is not a manifold, so the theorem does not say anything about it!

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about the open unit disk, it's not complete (sequences approaching a point on the boundary are Cauchy but not convergent).

If you're talking about the closed unit disk, it's not a manifold but a manifold-with-boundary. Hopf-Rinow applies only to manifolds without boundary.

Comment: Whops... Thanks a lot.